# Forming a commitee problem

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a committee be formed from four men and six women with five people, and not all of the three O'Hara sisters can be on the committee?

How would I breakdown this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- How many ways of forming a committee of five from ten individuals?
- How many of these have all three O'Hara sisters (consider forming a subcommittee of two others from seven others)?
- Subtract

Comment: Thanks, it was easier then I thought. So would it always be a good idea to consider the total arrangements possible in problems like these and the see how to work in the constraints?

Comment: Often but not always. Other correct methods should give the same solution - see user30628's response as an alternative.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ans - 51

Let A B C D be those 4 Men
and e f g h i j be those 6 Women

efABC egABC ehABC eiABC ejABC fgABC fhABC fiABC fjABC ghABC giABC gjABC hiABC hjABC ijABC

efACD egACD ehACD eiACD ejACD fgACD fhACD fiACD fjACD ghACD giACD gjACD hiACD hjACD ijACD

efBCD egBCD ehBCD eiBCD ejBCD fgBCD fhBCD fiBCD fjBCD ghBCD giBCD gjBCD hiBCD hjBCD ijBCD

eABCD fABCD gABCD hABCD iABCD jABCD

Comment: What about the committees with three or more women?

Comment: Did you dynamically generate this using a program?

Answer (score 0):

There are the three sisters on one side and the remaining 7 people on the other. If we choose no sister, it gives $7\choose5$ ways, if we choose one sister, it's $3\times{7\choose4}$ ways, and finally with two sisters we have $3\times{7\choose3}$ ways. Sum up the three numbers and that's the answer.

Comment: For the last one, don't you men 6 x 7C3

Comment: No, there are 3 ways to choose 2 sisters out of 3.

Comment: all right gotcha thanks